# Spring MVC + Freemarker Integration 404 Error

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, freemarker

I am having an issue integrating freemarker with spring. I have searched as much as I can and am now just confused.

The error I'm getting right now is a 404 error after the project deploys.

I'm hoping someone can point out where I'm going wrong and why the welcome file pages aren't getting loaded, either of them.

Here is my project structure

```
+freemaerker-project
  +idea 
  +src
    +main 
      +java
        +controllers/entity
      +resources   
      +webapp
        + WEB-INF 
          + freemarker
            + ftl templates
        +web.xml
        +spring-servlet.xml
+pom
```

POM:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.freemarker</groupId>
<artifactId>freemarker-spring</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.23</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

WEB.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
     version="2.4">

<display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HomeController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.freemarker.controllers.HomeController</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HomeController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>src/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>home.ftl</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Spring-Servlet.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="com.freemarker" />

    <!-- freemarker config -->
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="src/WEB-INF/freemarker"/>
    <property name="preferFileSystemAccess" value="false" />
</bean>

<!-- View resolvers  -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: What url you are trying to access and you get 404? Can you also post your application/server logs? Is there any exception printed?

Comment: After the project deploys and opens in the browser, all I get is "HTTP Status  404 - / Resource not available" and there are no errors in either Tomcat log.

Comment: `src/WEB-INF/freemarker` look suspicious... maybe `/WEB-INF/freemarker`?

Comment: Also `src/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml` should be `/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml`. `web.xml` and `spring-servlet.xml` files should be inside `WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: And please, extract your generated war and show us the result